# Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1

Tags: android

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
>        Required by:
>            project :
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
>   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom'.
>   Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/216.58.221.110] failed: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: show your gradle file

Comment: Add your gradle to your question

Comment: @TejasPandya

The gradle file might contain confidential informations.

Comment: @Martin obviously you can hide that information from image

Comment: @TejasPandya Yes and I have done so many times. It can be quite time consuming making sure nothing shows up which must not show up.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1, then use only google() repository
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you're opening an existing project using `Android Studio 3.0` Preview 5 or later, follow the prompts to automatically update your project to the latest version of the Android plugin.

To manually update your project, include the maven `repo` and change the plugin version in your project-level `build.gradle` file as follows :

Apply this:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    ...
    // You need to add the following repository to download the
    // new plugin.
    google()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha5'
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> From version 26.0.0 of support libraries make sure that the
>   repositories section includes a maven section with the
>   "https://maven.google.com" endpoint.

[Read Document](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html)

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
  }
}
```

> For Gradle build tools plugin version 3.0.0, you can use google()
>   repository:

[Read Document](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Comment: As if we had not had enough of gradle, now they want us to use Maven as well. Tut tut.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone currently blocked by this,

1 find the version in maven [image: centeral]

2 See the repository link at the bottom where it says "Note: this artifact located at ....

in your build script repositories, create a build script repository entry using the link from maven central as below

```
   maven {
        url 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/'

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

simple, if you got this issue you need to change add/change google() above on jcenter().
like that:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        //you need to change add/change google() above on jcenter()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

try it, i think its help to solve your problem..